# How to specify a sequence of elements instead of an array of elements in a .NET WCF Web Service?

Tags: .net, wcf, xsd, wsdl

I have a .NET 4 WCF web service which takes a data contract with an optional enumerable of strings.  For example:

Service Code:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
public string Something {
    get { return _Something; }
    set { _Something= value; }
}
private string _Something;

[DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
public string[] MoreThings {
    get { return _MoreThings.ToArray<string>(); }
    set { _MoreThings  = new List<string>(value); }
}
private List<string> _MoreThings = new List<string>();
```

WSDL:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="MyDataContract">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="Something" type="xsd:string" /> 
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="MoreThings" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfstring" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

I'm trying to interface with the service from a number of different platforms, but one is Perl using SOAP::WSDL (and wsdl2perl.pl in particular), which seems to be failing on recognizing "ArrayOfstring".  Is there anything I can do in my code so that the WSDL would read like this:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="MyDataContract">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="Something" type="xsd:string" /> 
      <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MoreThings" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" /> 
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

I'm open to other suggestions, as well.  Basically, I'm trying to do something similar to declaring a method MyOperation(string something, params string[] moreThings), where any number of additional moreThings parameters may be passed, but in a way that doesn't cause interop issues with non-.NET platforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML validation with XSD: how to avoid caring about the sequence of the elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325247/xml-validation-with-xsd-how-to-avoid-caring-about-the-sequence-of-the-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot achieve that with `DataContractSerializer` - you must switch to `XmlSerializer`. You can simply take your schema you need and let tools (run VS command prompt) generate class for you.

- For `DataContractSerizlizer` use: `svcutil.exe /dataContractsOnly File.xsd` but as I mentioned before I don't think that `DataContract` can represent your schema
- For `XmlSerializer` use:  `xsd.exe /classes File.xsd`

Once you have the class file simply add it to your service project and use it in your service's operations. In case of `XmlSerializer` you must mark either whole service contract / implementation or operation contracts / implementations using types generated by `XSD.exe` with `XmlSerializerFormat` attribute.

Comment: Thumbs up for pointing me to xsd.exe, I hadn't used that before.  Unfortunately, the end result was getting the same WSDL.  After some more digging, I found that the real problem was that my ArrayOfstring was defined as another ComplexType *below* my data contract, and if I moved it *above* my data contract, SOAP::WSDL did just fine with it.  But then it bombed on other things, prompting me to vow to never use SOAP::WSDL again.