# How to cause the WSDL generated by WCF to contain an xsd:any element?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, wsdl

So, I have the following data contract:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://abc/Services/Data")]
public abstract class AbcObject
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement[] Any { get; set; }
}
```

My expectation is to see the following corresponding `xs:complexType` element in the generated wsdl:

```
<xs:complexType name="AbcObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xsd:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

However, what I actually see is:

```
<xs:complexType name="AbcObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Any" type="q1:ArrayOfXmlElement" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

So, this is not what I want, but I am kind of puzzled how to get the `xsd:any` generated for me.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

As per [jamiemeyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1375636/jamiemeyer) advice I have changed the `DFObject.Any` property to be of type `XmlAttribute[]`. Here is the result:

```
<xs:complexType name="DFObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Any" type="q1:ArrayOfArrayOfanyType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Although the result is different, it is still not `xsd:any`.

Comment: Looking at an old project, I believe that if you modify XmlElement[] to XmlAttribute[] you will achieve the results you are after.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML validation with XSD: how to avoid caring about the sequence of the elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325247/xml-validation-with-xsd-how-to-avoid-caring-about-the-sequence-of-the-elements)

Comment: I am out of context now, but I do not see how it helps.